# Bucket policy to block all access except for a list of users with varying access restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Need help formulating a complex bucket policy -

I own a s3 bucket with highly sensitive content in an AWS account that I do not administer. I wish to introduce a bucket policy to prevent undesired access, including by users with permissive s3 access IAM policies (which I cannot control because I'm not the account admin).

My bucket policy is currently blocking all access except for my own IAM user - it looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "<my IAM userId>",
                        "<my AWS AccountId>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine, but now I need to add permissions for certain roles to be able to read/write anywhere in their respective folder under the root folder, so the bucket policy needs to allow the following (and block anything else):

1. allow my own IAM user full access to manage the bucket and its entire content
2. Allow `roleA` read/write access to their respective folder `folderA` under the root folder
3. Allow `roleB` read/write access to their respective folder `folderB` under the root folder

Can someone advise how best to acheive this outcome?

Comment: Perhaps 3 deny statements: 1) to deny s3:* if aws:userId is not one of your user IDs and aws:PrincipalArn is not one of the two named role ARNs, 2) to deny s3:* on all resources if the aws:PrincipalArn is the roleA ARN and the s3:prefix is not folderA/, and 3) similarly for roleB/folderB.

Answer (score 2):

This will work assuming that you do not have any files on the root of the bucket, if you have files on the root of the bucket anyone with access to folder1 or folder2 will have access to them too.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyBucketAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "<my IAM userId>",
                        "<roleA unique ID>",
                        "<roleB unique ID>",
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyFolderAAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>/folderA/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "<my IAM userId>",
                        "<roleA unique ID>",
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyFolderBAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>/folderB/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "<my IAM userId>",
                        "<roleB unique ID>",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get an IAM role Unique ID you can do so by using the following command

```
aws iam get-role --role-name RoleAName --query Role.RoleId --output text
```

or if you do not have IAM permission, you can ask someone with Role A access to do

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --query UserId --output text
```

And copy paste anything before the ":"

Example

AROA1234567890EXAMPLE:example@example.com -> Copy the AROA1234567890EXAMPLE

Comment: Maybe also worth adding conditions on s3:prefix per my earlier comment, to try to address the unintended accessibility of root objects.